# Escape command in echo

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I have some really long and complex command containing both types of quotes: " and ', for example like:

```
cd folder && command --hel="p_me:'please' anyone:'here?'" ; command2 --end='my:"trouble"'
```

I want to throw it into the echo command. But it does not work easily, I have to insert it into another quotes and escape some quotes inside the command. This should be okay usually, but unfortunately this time I can not change the command itself (and escape any quotes inside).

How to echo a command containing both types of quotes without its modification? How to escape the quotes on-run for echo?

Comment: Why do you need to echo this? What's the goal?

Comment: It is not the echo exactly, I have to pass the command to the cron's jsub command, but it pretty much behaves the same way as echo does when interpreting its input

Comment: *Cron's* jsub command? What exactly do you mean? Which cron? Please show what you're actually trying to do. `echo foo` prints `foo`, and there are any number of ways to print `foo` (i.e., do what echo does), but if you're using some other command, not all of those ways will be applicable to you.

Comment: The whole line is `jsub -N cron-89 -once -quiet foo` (where foo is my command). But the interpretation of my command works the same way as echo does, it strips the outer quotes (if not escaped), but this time I can not escape them before unfortunately

Comment: The escape character in shell is always `\ `, so if you want to print `that is "incredible"`, you must do `echo "that is \"incredible\""`

Comment: @aleskva which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was doing this every time, but this time I can not change the command, so I can not escape anything inside. Therefore I'm asking if I can escape them on-run by using some command, or if there is any other possibility

Comment: We use Trusty Tahr

Comment: you should use `cd folder && { command ...; command2 ...; }`. Otherwise `command2` will be executed even when `cd folder` fails. .... Anyways, I feel like this is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a heredoc:

```
xargs -d $'\n' echo <<'EOF'
cd folder && command --hel="p_me:'please' anyone:'here?'" ; command2 --end='my:"trouble"'
EOF
```

Example:

```
$ xargs -d $'\n' echo <<'EOF'
cd folder && command --hel="p_me:'please' anyone:'here?'" ; command2 --end='my:"trouble"'
EOF

cd folder && command --hel="p_me:'please' anyone:'here?'" ; command2 --end='my:"trouble"'
```

I don't know what `jsub` is and I couldn't find it in [the repositories for 14.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=jsub&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any), but unless it runs a shell or can interpret shell syntax, I don't think this will work the way you think it will.

```
xargs -d $'\n' jsub -N cron-89 -once -quiet <<'EOF'
cd folder && command --hel="p_me:'please' anyone:'here?'" ; command2 --end='my:"trouble"'
EOF
```